# Logic Connective involving implication and biconditions(FOL/Tarski' World)

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm trying to solve the following two problems where I'm asked to translate these English sentences into First Order Language (FOL) by using Tarski's World symbols. I'll appreciate it very much if anyone can help me confirm my solutions to the problems.

**Question:**

1) If $e$ is a tetrahedron, then it's to the right of $b$ if and only if it is also in front of $b$.

2) $e$ is in front of $d$ unless $e$ is a large tetrahedron.

**my solution:**

1) Tet(e) ⇒ (RightOf(e,b) ⇔ FrontOf(e,b))

I'm not very certain for this problem. Can it be that:

(Tet(e) ⇒ RightOf(e,b)) ⇔ (Tet(e) ⇒ LeftOf(e,b)) the correct solution? Because if the iff symbol is in between RightOf(e,b) and FrontOf(e,b), then it only shows the iff relation between these two and not related Tet(e) at all.

2) ¬(Large(e) ∧ Tet(e)) ⇒ FrontOf(e,d):

For this problem, the "Q unless P" translates to "If ¬P then Q", at first I thought of using ¬(Large(e) ∨ Tet(e)), but on the second thought that if we have "Small Tetrahedron" it will still satisfy the "If ¬P" aka if it's the case that P is large Tetrahedron. So I used conjunction instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution for 1) is correct.  The second one (Tet(e) ⇒ RightOf(e,b)) ⇔ (Tet(e) ⇒ LeftOf(e,b)) turns out to be equivalent, but it is not a direct translation of the original English sentence. In the original sentence, you have the biconditional as part of the consequent.

Your solution (and reasoning) for 2) is correct